# Covert object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

How can I convert an object into an array of objects and add key and value?

My current object

```
{   "0": "Ann_B", "1": "Billy_P", "2": "Carly_C", "3": "David_L"   }
```

I want it to be

```
[
    {  "value": "Ann_B_Aii", "name": "Ann B Aii",   },
    {  "value": "Billy_P", "name": "Billy P"  },
    {  "value": "Carly_C", "name": "Carly C"  },
    {  "value": "David_L", "name": "David L"  },
]
```

I used `Object.entries` and replace _ to space

Comment: where do you get the value of `name` from?

Comment: `name` is from `id` and replace `_` to a space

Answer (score 2):

You could take the values and iterate by getting new objects.

```js
var data = { 0: "Ann_B", 1: "Billy_P", 2: "Carly_C", 3: "David_L" },
    result = Object.values(data).map(v => ({ id: v, name: v.replace(/_/g, ' ') }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You can make this accept middle names or multi last names by adding a `g` flag to the regex in the replace i.e. `result = Object.values(data).map(v => ({ id: v, name: v.replace(/_/g, ' ') }));`

Comment: @MarcusParsons, right, the replacement should be global.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` and `.map()` methods:

```js
let data = {
  "0": "Ann_B",
  "1": "Billy_P",
  "2": "Carly_C",
  "3": "David_L"
};

let result = Object.values(data)
                   .map(v => ({id: v, name: v.replace(/_/g, ' ')}));
                   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I assume that `d` contains your input object; working example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/L5c4wtpy/4/))

```
Object.values(d).map(v=>({value:v,name:v.replace(/_/g,' ')}));
```